# React re-rendering modal component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have 2 modal windows which I have defined as react components. As soon as the user on our sites click on a button, the first modal renders and indicates that some processing is happening. We are making some API calls while this modal is processing. Based on the results of the API call, I need to be able to replace this modal with another modal window that has some other content in it. Currently this is the code I have, but this does not render the second modal window.

```
import React, { PropTypes, Component } from 'react';

import * as statusList from './status';

class AppStatus extends Component {
  static propTypes = {
    component: PropTypes.string
  }

  render() {
    const { component, ...statusProps } = this.props;
    const Status = statusList[component]; 

    return (
        <div id="app-status" className="expanded row align-center align-middle">
          <Status {...statusProps} />
        </div>
    );

  }
}

export default AppStatus;
```

The behavior I am seeing is that the first modal shows first, when the second component has to render the modal completely disappears.

What am I am doing wrong here? How do I make this render?

Comment: So where are exactly are you drawing your modals? If they are rendered by the `Status` component we need to be able to see how that component works.

Comment: also i would like to see the component that does the api requests and probably renders the AppStatus component.

Comment: @PedroCastilho the Status component is indeed what would render the two modals I have. `import _Processing from './processing';
export { _Processing as Processing };` is an example of one of the components. And the modal has nothing much it just has one icon and a text under it.

Comment: @radix the API call is done from a saga and while the api call is processing, these modal components are being shown to the user of the application. The saga dispatches an action to set the application status to busy and render the `AppStatus`. Here is the line that I use to set my application status in my saga `yield put(appStatusSwitch('busy', 'AppSubmit', 'app.status.text.processing-application'));` and then in my `aap.js` I check for application busy and render AppStatus. `{isBusy && (
        <AppStatus {...appStatus} intl={intl} productDetails={product} />
      )}`